# Sublime Automatic Build System Text Files

Tags: sublimetext2, text-files, sublimetext, sublimetext3, build-system

I am trying to create a build system that will detect a file with a .txt extension then use the program I provided. I know it has something to do with scope, but I can't seem to get it to work.

> `selector`
> If the **Tools | Build System | Automatic** option is set, Sublime Text will automatically find the corresponding build system for the active file by matching `selector` to the file's scope.

-https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/build-systems.html

```
{"cmd": ["cmd", "/k", "python C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Documents\\MyProgramming\\NotesTODO\\notesTODOs.py $file", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "scope.txt",
"shell": "true"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["cmd", "/k", "python C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Documents\\MyProgramming\\NotesTODO\\notesTODOs.py", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "text.plain",
    "shell": "true"
}
```

First, you had `$file` listed twice in your `"cmd"` line, so I removed one. Second, the scope for plain text is `text.plain` (there is also `text.html`, `text.tex.latex`, etc.). You probably don't need the `file_regex`, but I don't think it's hurting anything, so that's your call.